# invalid qualifier error when defining variable for worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I want to define Sheeet1 in the current workbook.  The name of the workbook is dynamic. this code gives me an "invalid qualifier" error

```
   Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Set ws1 = ActiveWorkbook.Name.Sheets("Sheet1")
```

thanks in advance for the help and sorry if it's obvious and I am just not seeing it.

Comment: The `Name` of any workbook is a `String`. If you want to get the `Sheets` collection of the active workbook, do `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets`, or better, `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dont use name - use this

```
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Set ws1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
```

Comment: FWIW this code will blow up if there's a `Chart` sheet named `Sheet1` in the active workbook. That's why you use the `Worksheets` collection when you want a `Worksheet` object.